# How do i modify a link that generates current date instead of static date for everyday

Tags: php, date, variables, hyperlink

Here is a code

```
<?php    echo "<li><iframe src=\"http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx.aspx?edcode=11&eddate=**04/10/2014** &querypage=43\" ></iframe></li>"; ?>
```

Instead of this fixed date, I would like to dynamically get current date for everyday.. so I tried:

```
<?php    echo "<li><iframe src=\"http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx.aspx?edcode=11&eddate=<?=date('d/m/Y')?> &querypage=43\" ></iframe></li>"; ?>
```

but didn't work, is there any other method?

Comment: Have you tried looking for that site? What is that site?

Answer (score 2):

You have to append  the php date like

```
<?php  echo "<li><iframe src=\"http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx.aspx?edcode=11&eddate=".date('d/m/Y')."&querypage=43\"></iframe></li>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested php/echo tags which is invalid. Remove the `<?=` & `?>` tag.

```
<?php echo "<li><iframe src=\"http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx.aspx?edcode=11&eddate=".date('d/m/Y')."&querypage=43\" ></iframe></li>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be written like this. No need for more PHP tag because the code is already inside echo. Use concatenation instead:

```
  <?php  echo "<li><iframe src=\"http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx.aspx?edcode=11&eddate=".date('d/m/Y')."&querypage=43\" ></iframe></li>"; ?>
```